# Is there any advantage to using keys @array instead of 0 .. $#array?

Tags: perl

I was quite surprised to find that the [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) function happily works with arrays:

> ```
> keys HASH
> keys ARRAY
> keys EXPR
> ```
>
> Returns a list consisting of all the keys of the named hash, or the
>   indices of an array. (In scalar context, returns the number of keys or
>   indices.)

Is there any benefit in using `keys @array` instead of `0 .. $#array` with respect to memory usage, speed, etc., or are the reasons for this functionality more of a historic origin?

Seeing that `keys @array` holds up to `$[` modification, I'm guessing it's historic :

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wE 'local $[=4; my @array="a".."z"; say join ",", keys @array;'
Use of assignment to $[ is deprecated at -e line 1.
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you provided actually has one important reason you might use/not use `keys`:

> As a side effect, calling keys() resets the internal interator of the HASH or ARRAY (see each). In particular, calling keys() in void context resets the iterator with no other overhead.

That would cause `each` to reset to the beginning of the array.  Using `keys` and `each` with arrays might be important if they ever natively support sparse arrays as a real data-type.

All that said, with so many array-aware language constructs like `foreach` and `join` in perl, I can't remember the last time I used `0..$#array`.

Comment: For me, `0 .. $#array` is a convenient construct when working with `map`, `grep` and `sort`: `my @wantedIndices = grep { $array[$_] =~ /foo/ } 0 .. $#array;`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a sparse array?

Comment: A sparse array is basically a hash with numerical keys that retains the order of the items. If you make a an array with @a[1], @[7], and @[100_000_000] set you get a big array with tons of undef in it. 99% of the time you can use a hash and be happy with it but for large sparse arrays doing the key sort over and over sucks.

Comment: @Zaid, if you miss $#array so much, you could also try scalar(@array). That should return the number of elements that are there in the array.

Comment: @Bee : They're not the same thing unless `$[` is 1, which is usually not the case.

Answer (score 4):

Mark has it partly right, I think.  What he's missing is that each now works on an array, and, like the each with hashes, each with arrays returns two items on each call.  Where `each` %hash returns key and value, `each` @array also returns key (index) and value.

```
while (my ($idx, $val) = each @array)
{
  if ($idx > 0 && $array[$idx-1] eq $val)
  {
     print "Duplicate indexes: ", $idx-1, "/", $idx, "\n";
  }
}
```

Thanks to Zaid for asking, and [jmcnamara](http://perlmonks.org/?node=jmcnamara) for bringing it up on perlmonks' CB.  I didn't see this before - I've often looped through an array and wanted to know what index I'm at.  This is waaaay better than manually manipulating some `$i` variable created outside of a loop and incremented inside, as I expect that `continue`, `redo`, etc., will survive this better.

So, because we can now use `each` on arrays, we need to be able to reset that iterator, and thus we have `keys`.

Comment: I didn't miss it, I just missed mentioning it. :-)  Good catch and good explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I actually think you've answered your own question: it returns the valid indices of the array, no matter what value you've set for `$[`. So from a generality point of view (especially for library usage), it's more preferred.

The version of Perl I have (5.10.1) doesn't support using `keys` with arrays, so it can't be for historic reasons.

Comment: You're right... [it got added in Perl 5.12.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html#each%2c-keys%2c-values-are-now-more-flexible). Is there anything else other than the `$[` compliance though? It's not every day that you find `$[` holding a non-default value...

Comment: @Zaid: Try using it with a sparse array, and see if the keys that come back are also sparse. (I don't have a 5.12 to test with.)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by a sparse array.

Comment: @Zaid: Example: `my @a; $a[4] = $a[42] = 42; print keys @a;` Does that print 4 and 42, or 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 42?

Comment: `keys @arr` always gives you the full range.  The intermediate elements are undefined, not nonexistent.

Comment: $[ might actually be removed from a future version of Perl. Expending ANY effort on being compliant with that is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your example, you are putting them in a list; So, in a list context

`keys @array` will be replaced with all elements of array 
whereas `0 .. $#array` will do the same but as array slicing; So, instead `$array[0 .. $#array]` you can also mention `$array[0 .. (some specific index)]`

Comment: Quibble: `keys @array` gives you a list of the *indices* of the array, not of its elements.